# track down why PSSession is in broken state?

Tags: powershell

I have a remote invocation that keeps breaking and I don't know why, but I also have no idea on how to start investigating this.

The msdn documentation for the PSSession object doesn't seem to have much in it, are there error codes somewhere I can access?  How do you go about trying to determine why a PSSession connection was broken?

Comment: I think it would help to describe what you're doing, show some code, the error message(s) encountered, etc. Is this a long running session? How long?

Comment: I don't understand that, what I'm asking for is fairly generic.  When you encounter a PSSession with a state of 'Broken', how do you go about determining why it broke?  By 'why' I mean simply, can you determine if it broke due to a timeout being met, due to slow network connectivity, and so forth.  Things that I would expect Powershell to be able to report regardless of how the application is designed in the first place.

Comment: don't get me wrong, I would love to take the time describing to you what's going on, I just don't understand how it's relevant to the question being asked.  Perhaps the question itself isn't clear?

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. You're looking for how to find the conditions that led to a broken session after the fact, in general. Understood (though I admit I have no idea).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ultimately found the issue, but I also found more info on debugging remoting in powershell.

Here's a video with an explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NI_8sJOu_fo&feature=youtu.be&t=33m12s

But in essence

```
Import-Module PSDiagnostics
Enable-PSWSManCombinedTrace
```

This starts logging extra information that you can pull up in the windows event log (the video has details).  Just enable it on the remote server then pop it open.

For my specific issue, I was updating the password on the server then calling New-PSSession with the new credentials and it apparently was grabbing the old session from cache.  I would do more work, but windows would eventually break the connection in the middle of the work.

I had to call Remove-PSSession after finishing the password update, once that was done the subsequent calls to New-PSSession did the right thing.

Basically, I didn't understand the caching mechanisms behind the scenes for the PSSession functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a while trying to pass a variable to an Office 365 command using the cmdline.  Found this works (even if no output to screen happens when it executes):

```
param($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4)
$b = "set-msoluserprincipalname -newuserprincipalname " + $p1 + " -
userprincipalname " + $p2

invoke-expression $b

# use invoke-expression rather than invoke-command
```